# How to use igraph in R to graph twitter text data

Tags: r, twitter, igraph

I'm looking for a bit of help filling in the numerous blanks in my experience when it comes to using `igraph` package in R to create a graph of the common words used by 5 twitter accounts. My aim is to see which keywords the accounts share and identify others that are common to 1 account and not others.

I've created a wordcloud from the tweet text but I'd appreciate any help from the communities in converting (if possible) that to a graph. So far I have a `TermDocumentMatrix` using the `tm` package showing the frequency from the `wordcloud` and I'd like to incorporate that frequency data into the final plot as well.

I'm not sure what format my data needs to be or where I should start (dataframe, Corpus, Matrix) Any pointers?

This is what manipulations I have done to clean and process the data

Clean up the tweet text stored in a dataframe called tweetsDF and column "text" to find the common words used. Start by removing the hashtags from the text using the `qdapRegex` package:

```
Text <- rm_hash(tweetsDF$text, clean=TRUE, trim=TRUE)
# Remove the twitter shortened urls using the qdapRegex package

TextNoShortURL <-rm_twitter_url(Text, trim = TRUE, clean = TRUE,extract = FALSE)

# Create a Term Document Matrix but remove the Punctuation, common english words and exclude "and" "the" "for" using the tm package

TextTDM = TermDocumentMatrix(TextCorpus,control = list(removePunctuation =TRUE,stopwords("english"),stopwords =c("the","for","and"),removeNumbers = FALSE))

# Convert it to a Matrix

TextMatrix <- as.matrix(TextTDM)

# Get the frequency of the words found in the text

MainWord_freqs = sort(rowSums(TextMatrix), decreasing=TRUE) 

# Convert it to a dataframe

TextDF <- data.frame(word=names(MainWord_freqs), freq=MainWord_freqs)

# And you end up with a dataframe contains each word and how often it was included in text, the  twitter handle isn't included here but I assume I can mutate the dataframe to include it  

<PRE>
             row.names        word        freq
1            shop             shop        8765
2            food             food        924
3            drink            drink        8273
..
</PRE>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here so I have a data source suitable for igraph that will allow me to associate the twitter handle XYZ with the main words used

Comment: For the community to help, you need to provide some data and your code so far.

Comment: I'm not able to attach or link to the text but if you assume I start out with a dataframe containing the tweets with the text of the tweets stored in tweetsDF$text. I use qdapRegex and tm packages to extract and clean the text

Comment: Generally, you should abstract from your problem a bit and provide reproducible example code, which people can copy, paste & run. This makes it a bit more difficult for you, but easier for all others. Here's how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Note that my code is reproducible - you can copy, paste & run ist in R and reproduce the output more or less, whereas yours still isn't. For example, there's still example data missing. Please read the info provided by the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try some sort of a bipartite graph like this:

```
library(igraph)
library(tm)
library(reshape2)
tweets <- c("This is a test", "This is another test", "blah")
mat <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(tweets))))
g <- graph.data.frame(subset(melt(mat), !!value, -value), directed = FALSE)
V(g)$color <- rep(2:3, dim(mat))
plot(g)
```

[image]

---

### Add:

```
library(igraph)
library(tm)
library(reshape2)
tweets <- c("This is a test test test test test", "This This is another test", "blah")
mat <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(tweets))))
g <- graph.data.frame(subset(melt(mat, value.name = "width"), !!width), directed = FALSE)
V(g)$color <- rep(2:3, dim(mat))
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi lukeA, your comment about melt helped me move on my thinking. if I a dataframe with the structure df$word,df$Tweeter,df$freq how would I create a graph that showed stronger relations between word and tweeter for higher values of frequency

Comment: You can specify the edge widths in `E(g)$width` or map them in the plot command using `plot(..., edge.width = my_count_var, ...)`. See my edit above. (Note the newly added repetitions in `tweets`.)

Comment: Oops, I thought I saved the edit, but it seems I didn't - so here it's again (2nd screenshot)...

Comment: would  Mygraph <- graph.data.frame(TextDF.melt)  THEN Mygraph$weight <- TextDF.melt$value work as well?

Comment: Try it out. `E(Mygraph)$weight <- ...` and `plot(Mygraph, edge.width =E(Mygraph)$weight)`.